# Search not working after custom request handler

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-bootgrid

I have modified the default bootgrid using the request handler but it seems now that the search phrase is not working.How can i pass the search phrase using request handler ?

Also i want to change the sort order based on branch after custom request handler.How can i change the sort order based on branch programmatic after calling request handler?

The refresh button is not working.How to reload grid when refresh button is clicked?

My Table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="product_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>

            <th data-column-id="sbranch" data-header-align="center" data-align="center">Branch</th>
            <th data-column-id="subject_code" data-header-align="center" data-align="center">Code</th>
            <th data-column-id="sname" data-header-align="center" data-align="center">Subject Name</th>
            <th data-column-id="smode" data-header-align="center" data-align="center">Mode</th>
            <th data-column-id="ssemester" data-header-align="center" data-align="center" data-order="asc">Semester</th>
            <th data-column-id="stype" data-header-align="center" data-align="center">Type</th>
            <th data-column-id="scredit" data-header-align="center" data-align="center">Credit</th>
            <th data-column-id="sslot" data-header-align="center" data-align="center">Slot</th>
            <th data-column-id="syear" data-header-align="center" data-align="center">Year</th>             
            <th data-column-id="slink" data-header-align="center" data-align="center"  data-formatter="link">Download</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Custom request handler

```
requestHandler: function (request) {
       //Add your id property or anything else
        request.branch = $("#branch").val();

       request.id = "b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed";
       return request;
},
```

Comment: Can you show your full javascript where you build your bootgrid?

Comment: Also, did you see my answer to your last question?

Comment: Can you help me out how to send search phrase using refresh handler?

Comment: I think I can help you, but first you need to go back to your previous question, and tell me if I could help you solve that problem. Next step, we try to solve this. If you don't give a feedback to answers, people will not be motivated to help you anymore.

Comment: Yes i was able to solve the problem with your help..i dont have enough reputation to upvote the answer right now..

Comment: Also do you require the full javascript.?its lots of code..The sorting is working but now since i am passing the variable using request handler i think i lost control of search phrase..

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted, though. If you can share at least the full code you use to build bootgrid, it may help us to identify you problem.

Answer (score 0):

There a are few thinks you can do by refreshing is you can do this in your js:

```
location.reload();
```

or you can reload the HTML by reopening it:

```
`window.open('[NAME_OF_YOUR_HTML]','_self',false);
```

Is the HTML that you showed hardcoded in the HTML or dynamically generated by JS?

Comment: This is not efficient, and it doesn't answer the question.